# How to properly set focus on a React IconButton via React API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, focus

I have the following react control I have created:

```
export class MyButtonControl extends React.Component<MyButtonControlProps, {}> {
    private iconButtonRef: IconButton;

    public componentDidMount() {
        this.setFocus();
    }

    private setFocus() {
        const element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.iconButtonRef) as HTMLElement;
        element.focus();
    }

    public render() {
        const buttonProps: IButtonProps = {
            className: "my-button",
            title: "my button"
        };
        return (
            <IconButton {...buttonProps} ref={c => this.iconButtonRef = c} />
        );
    }
}
```

The control is extending React's `IconButton`.

As you can see I set focus inside `setFocus`, however I am doing this in a way I do not like: manually! It is not desired because it does not scale well.

#### Properly setting focus

Is it possible to do this via the React API? I did search inside `IconButton`, but there is no `focus()` or `setFocus()`.

I did see though that `IconButton` basically renders a `BaseButton` (also a part of React's library), so I thought I could do this:

```
export class MyButtonControl ... {
    private iconButtonRef: BaseButton;

    ...

    private setFocus() {
        this.iconButtonRef.focus();
    }

    public render() {
        ...
        return (
            <IconButton ... ref={c => this.iconButtonRef = c as any as BaseButton} />
        );
    }
}
```

Because `BaseButton` has a `focus` method exposed. But the code fails because, by debugging, I can see that the object in `iconButtonRef` does not contain a definition of `focus` being of type `ComponentWithInjectedProps`.

But you get the idea, what I am trying to achieve. Is it possible in some way?

Comment: `But the code fails :(`  
how does it fail? what's the error you're getting?

Comment: `BaseButton` is a component that you created?

Comment: No, it is React's and so is `IconButton`